# Posting and redirecting to same page

Tags: php, ajax, post

So I am just trying to pass some usernames from one php webpage to another, and I cannot seem to figure it out. Maybe there is some trick I am missing...

```
$('#send-message-button').click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "composemessage.php",
                    data: { passedusername: "<?php echo $_GET['username']; ?>"},
                    success: function(msg) {
                        window.location.href = "composemessage.php";
                    },
                });
            });
```

The page is redirecting properly but the var_dump is null.

```
    $_POST['passedusername'] = $passedusername;
    var_dump($_POST['passedusername']);
```

I believe I remember something weird about redirecting to the same page you're posting to, but I cannot find anything on it now. 
Sincere thanks for any help. It is greatly appreciated!

Comment: remove the redirection and check the network tab for the reply of your ajax

Comment: your assignment is the other way around, check elon's answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP is stateless. You're posting something to a version of a page, and then you're being redirected to another instance of that page. A completely new session. Use the Network tab in the Inspector of your browser of choice to see what the page that's being posted to actually returns.

edit: As Elon states, you also have your assignment the other way around. Try doing a `print_r($_POST)` to see what's being returned.

Comment: Got it. So is an ajax post not the answer here? do I need to use a form?

Comment: AJAX posting is fine, but might be irrelevant in this page. It's mostly used to stay on the same page, but you're redirecting your users away anyway, so it might be better to use a regular form. If you do want to use AJAX posting, that's fine, but as that is Javascript, you'll need the inspector.

Answer (score 1):

`$passedusername` is local variable and probably is undefined.

Value sent by your code will be in `$_POST['passedusername']` so you should reverse you assignment to `$passedusername = $_POST['passedusername']`.